# How to load the library of Anaconda when using ipython(.ipynb) in Windows 7

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

When I run .ipynb file in Windows 7 the error is:

```
 ImportError  Traceback (most recent call last)
 `enter code here`<ipython-input-1-07bd6a3858d4> in <module>()
      2 
      3 import random
----> 4 import numpy as npenter code here
      5 from cs231n.data_utils import load_CIFAR10
      6 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I have already install the Anaconda Library in Windows 7.

How can I load the Anaconda Library when using run .ipynb file in ipython?

Comment: since anaconda installed python and all other packages, ipynb should get other packages if it can find python interpreter in your system.

Comment: sorry，I cannot Understand，I am a jackaroo ,What should do to solve it

Comment: I tried to say when you install anaconda, it installs python for you along with other packages. so if you can run a simple python code in notebook, you should be able to run a code with numpy (numpy is a part of anaconda installation) as well. you don't need to do anything (if your installation is correct) separately for ipython notebook.